# Nativescript update http response when app launches

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have an app I have inherited that is getting data from an API endpoint. We have found that when we change data on the API, the changes are not reflected in the app. If we uninstall and re-install the app on a mobile device, then the new data from the API is displayed. Here is an example of the Building Detail page:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Building } from "../shared/building/building";
import { HttpService } from "../services/http/http.service";
import {
    getString,
    setString
} from "application-settings";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'building-detail',
    templateUrl: 'building-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ["./building-detail-common.css"],
    providers: [ Building, HttpService ]
})

export class BuildingDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    paramName: string;
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute, 
        public building: Building, 
        private httpService: HttpService) {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
            (params) => {
                this.paramName = params['name']
            } 
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ON INIT FIRED " + this.paramName);
        let buildingInfo = JSON.parse(getString("buildingInfo"));
        for (let item of buildingInfo) {
            if (item.attributes.title === this.paramName) {
                this.building.name = item.attributes.title;
                this.building.desc = item.attributes.body.value;
                let imageEndpoint = "file/file/" + item.relationships.field_building_image.data.id;
                let imageUrl = this.httpService.getData(imageEndpoint)
                .subscribe(data => { 
                    this.building.image = "https://nav.abtech.edu" + data['data'].attributes.url;
                    console.log("The building image URL is " + this.building.image);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("Error is " + error);
                });
            }
        }

     }
}
```

I am happy to share other files/code if you would like to look at those. Thanks!

Comment: Which platform you have this issue with? Is it possible for you to show us a GIF of what you see?

Comment: Here is screenshot from the app: https://snag.gy/KIwZQY.jpg

Comment: The reason I specifically asked for a GIF is to understand what exactly you are facing. `ngOnInit` is something that is executed only when your component is created, it will never be executed again. Also there is difference between app launch and resume, if you want to update data every time when user opens the app, you should listen to resume event and perform apis calls inside ngZone.

Comment: The data does not change very often on the backend. Is there a way to force a reinstall for people who already have the app installed. Bump the version maybe?

Comment: Sorry, that's absolutely unnecessary or not make sense at all. Just fetch the data when you want, like whenever user opens / resumes to app. Use push notification / data message if you want to notify user immediately when data changes on backend.

Comment: Summarised our discussion as an answer, so it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your data is not being updated is not because the ngOnInit is not being executed, it's because you're caching the old value and reloading it each time the app is run. You're caching the data persistently across app runs with appSettings and that's why you are seeing the values stay the same until you uninstall.

If you don't want to show a cached value then don't read from the app settings, or at least don't read from appSettings until you've refreshed the data once.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnInit` is something that is executed only when your component is created, it will never be executed again.

Also there is difference between app launch and resume, if you want to update data every time when user opens the app, you should listen to resume event and perform apis calls inside `ngZone`

You may even use push notification / data message if you want to notify user immediately when data changes on backend